# Difference in stretching in internal preview and pdf preview

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport, export-to-pdf

I have textfield in detail band. It has stretch with overflow checked. Problem is, when I display large text inside field, it looks different in internal and pdf preview.
In the image, on the left is column displayed in internal studio preview, and on the right is in pdf.
I would like to have in pdf just like it's in internal preview, but I couldn't make it. 
I get data from stored procedure, and before every '04' is '\n' added in database. In internal preview, after each "ccc." text is moved in new line, but that's not the case in pdf. I don't have any style applied to textfield.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer myself, problem was solved when I changed linebreak policy. It looks like internal preview and pdf preview have different linebreak policy.
I went to tools->options, tab 'Export Options' -> pdf and then tab 'Other options' and checked 'Force linebreak policy', as in picture. After doing that, column in pdf and internal preview looks same.
[image]